# failed to create a ‘System.Windows.Input.ICommand’ from the text

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

hi in my silverlight5 and mvvm pattern,
 i had one mainpage that page contains one button,

```
<Button Command="MyCommand"> Click Me </Button>
```

This above error can occur when binding a Command inside a Xaml file.

Why this error coming.. Any Help..

Answer (score 4):

have you tried

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"> Click Me </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is,

In fact, the problem with this syntax reside in the way we call the command. The previous example were not using the Binding syntax.

i used the Binding keyword.

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"> Click Me </Button>
```

Of course, you need bind to a ICommand property to the desired command.

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get {
        return ....
    }
}
```